# Am I compromised if Microsoft can identify me without browser content?

Tags: email, chrome, windows-7

I am using Windows 7 and I had to re-install Chrome recently.

In doing this, once I had deleted my browser history and used BleachBit, I told my email server (Outlook) what email address I was accessing, then provided it my password.

Now, after re-installing Chrome, the Outlook server knows the email address I use, despite that I have deleted browser history and used BleachBit. It only requires the password.

How does Microsoft know who I am when I have not identified myself? Have I compromised my anonymity on the internet by the resent re-installation?

Comment: "told my email server" -- what server where? Outlook.com? Did you mean "server" or "service"? The "Outlook server" knows your email address? Of course it does, you are registered with it. I think you need to explain what's actually going on. Your details make no sense. Do you simply mean that Chrome auto-filled your login details on a site?

Comment: If you cleared your history, **then** logged into a site, then reinstalled the browser, then, yes, it will remember your login to that site (it's still saved during a reinstall)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have credentials saved in the credential cache? BleachBit might not touch that. Check in Credential Manager (which you should be able to find in Control Panel or just search for it from the start menu).

You might also check the Mail dialog in Control Panel, as that will likely have your email address configured, and may be part of your Windows identity that can be supplied to a website.